# Is it possible to flash CM for Samsung S3 I9300 on different version?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3

Is it possible to flash CM on a different version? The other one is a SCH-I939 which was bought in China. Can someone explain to me how I can do it and why I can't flash it? I flashed CM13 on the SCH-I939 but it shows not SIM card. The sim card is a US one and works on other phones so there is definitely no problems with it.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply no.

i939 is a China Telecom variant, and has a CDMA baseband, along with other minor differences (there's a variant of i939 itself that even differs in dimensions). Unless the build was specifically marked as compatible with multiple variants (e.g.  S3 Qualcomm versions, aka `d2lte`, share a single CM build), the build will be limited to that model only. It's even more obvious considering i9300 is a GSM-only device.

Comment: Just checked around our local forums (I'm Chinese myself), and unfortunately there doesn't seem to be even CM11 available. Carrier variant phone users here are not tech savvy at all, so it's not surprising that there's almost no development.

Comment: @TheProgrammerG Theoretically yes, but realistically no. It's not something an inexperienced guy can do in days, nor is there any precise tutorial to follow.